# Precompile JSP in Tomcat 8 Ant script

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, ant, precompile

I have a Java application with Sprint framework. All the pages are accessed by a Controller which process the request and return a jps ModelAndView with several params to render in the JSP file.

Do you know any way to precompile these JSP files? I'm able to generate the *_jsp.java files using this [ant script](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jspc.html) but I'm getting compilation errors trying to compile to .class like this one:

```
symbol:   method getELContext()
  location: variable _jspx_page_context of type PageContext
/home/user/apache-tomcat-8.5.14/webapps/project/WEB-INF/src/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/views/awarding/awarding_005finput/detail/applicant/awardingInputDetailApplicant_jsp.java:683: error: cannot find symbol
      _jspx_th_c_005fset_005f5.setValue(new org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression("/WEB-INF/views/awarding/awarding_input/detail/applicant/awardingInputDetailApplicant.jsp(68,5) '${!applicant.hasAnyConfirmedCandidacyGoal()}'",_jsp_getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(_jspx_page_context.getELContext(),"${!applicant.hasAnyConfirmedCandidacyGoal()}",java.lang.Object.class)).getValue(_jspx_page_context.getELContext()));
```

All errors are regarding to "symbol:   method getELContext()" ...

### Update

This is the Ant task I'm using to compile the jsp from the *_jsp.java generated by the jasper task:

```
<target name="compileJSPs">
        <mkdir dir="${tomcat.home}/work/Catalina/localhost/${project.name}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
        <mkdir dir="${tomcat.home}/work/Catalina/localhost/${project.name}/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        <javac destdir="${tomcat.home}/work/Catalina/localhost/${project.name}/WEB-INF/classes"
               optimize="off"
               debug="on" failonerror="false"
               srcdir="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/src"
               excludes="**/*.smap">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
                <fileset dir="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/lib">
                    <include name="*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
                <pathelement location="${tomcat.home}/lib"/>
                <fileset dir="${tomcat.home}/lib">
                    <include name="*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
                <fileset dir="${tomcat.home}/bin">
                    <include name="*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
            <include name="**"/>
            <exclude name="tags/**"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
```

Here I attach my tomcat_home/lib contain:

[image: Tomcat Home libs included]

Comment: How are you compiling it ? could be due to a missing `el-api` dependency at your `classpath`.

Comment: I attach the ant task I'm using to compile the *_jsp.java. I already added to my gradle build this dependency "compile group: 'javax.el', name: 'el-api', version: '2.2'" but I still get exactly the same error

Comment: `Tomcat 8` by default has `EL 3.0 API` in its `lib`. Since you are using it to compile `jsps` then you don't need it to explicitly define in your `gradle` build.
It's safe to remove `epl-*` from your `gradle` . As it might be conflicting with the one provided by tomcat.

Comment: Ok, I remove it from my gradle, but still the same error. Is there anything I could change in my ant script to make it works?

Comment: Please make sure `${tomcat.home}` exists on your machine and `${tomcat.home}/lib` has all the `el-*` jars in it.

Comment: Hi again, I attach my tomcat lib folder contain, as you can see above it seems all required libs are there, any idea?

Comment: Any idea brothers?